# Is It possible to read value from system environment value in react app?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I have react project and i want to get value from system environment variable not from .env file. How it can be possible in react app ?

Thank you.

I tried to get value from .env file and it work successfully. But i want value from system environment variable.

Comment: React is running in browser. You can't access visitor system env.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get env in compile process. The name should be REACT_APP_{YOUR_ENV_VAR}.

See official document:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Answer (score 0):

In a React app, you can access system environment variables directly by using process.env. However, keep in mind that environment variables set at the system level are not accessible in the browser directly. To access system environment variables in your React app, you'll need to use a build tool or server-side code to pass those values to your app.

Here's an example of how you can access system environment variables in a React app using a build tool like webpack:

Install the **dotenv-webpack** package as a development dependency in your project:

```
npm install dotenv-webpack --save-dev
```

Create a webpack configuration file (e.g., webpack.config.js) in the root of your project with the following content:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

 module.exports = {
    // other webpack configuration options...
       plugins: [
             new Dotenv(),
             ],
       };
```

Update your **package.json** file to include the webpack configuration file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
  "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
   "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
   }
}
```

Create a .env file in the root of your project and add your system environment variables with the format VARIABLE_NAME=variable_value.

In your React components, you can now access the system environment variables using **process.env.VARIABLE_NAME.** For example:

`console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY);`

Make sure to restart your development server or rebuild your app for the changes to take effect.

With this setup, you can define your system environment variables in the **.env** file, and Webpack will automatically inject them into your React app. This way, you can access the values using **process.env.VARIABLE_NAME** throughout your code.

Please note that in production environments, you'll need to configure the server or deployment platform to set the **system environment variables** appropriately.